# How to add Verification Code functionality to Custom Policy Azure

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm new to Azure Custom Policies and I have a policy that takes claims from a token (token_hint). But now I need to add the verification code sending for email field. I could not find an example having this in a custom policy. Any suggestions or links?

Answer (score 0):

Since these custom policies are hard to debug, I was carful to took exsisting ones and add mine so

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithReadOnlyEmail">
<DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
<Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
<Metadata>
    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
    <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
</Metadata>
<CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer"/>
</CryptographicKeys>
<InputClaimsTransformations>
    <!-- Copy the InvitationId to CopyInvitationId claim type-->
    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopyInvitationId"/>
</InputClaimsTransformations>
<InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"/>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="ReadOnlyInvitationId"/>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="displayName"/>
</InputClaims>
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource"/>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser"/>
    <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName"/>       
</OutputClaims>
<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail"/>
</ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD"/>
```

So I have a custom attirbute coming from a token hint as well as other email, display name like attributes too.